# Cache external image in a PhoneGap App

Tags: caching, cordova, local-storage

I have 3rd party images being used in a application. I don't want to download and package them in the app because it would violate copyright.

How can I have the application on first time opening, load all the images and cache them, so that if its opened again offline the images could still be accessed?

Comment: This blog post should set you on the right track http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/1/19/Downloading-files-to-a-PhoneGap-application--Part-1

Comment: Isn't caching the images a copyright violation in the same manner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using cache manifest: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html. Allows you specify content to be cached for offline use.

Change your html tag to:

```
<html manifest="cache.appcache">
```

In the cache.appcache file:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
index.html
image1.jpg
image2.jpg
```

Comment: Where is `cache.appacache` located?  If `index.html` in bundled inside the PhoneGap app I thought it couldn't use a remote manifest file for cross-origin reasons.

Comment: There is no cross-origin restrictions inside a PhoneGap application